# C# - How to use anonymous types with Dotfuscator.Net?

Tags: c#, obfuscation, dotfuscator

I have this piece of code in my C# application:

```
JObject personJson = JObject.FromObject(
    new
    {
        name = "John Doe",
        age = 34,
        height = 1.78,
        weight = 79.34
    });

Console.WriteLine(person);
```

And it logs:

```
{
    "name": "John Doe",
    "age": 34,
    "height": 1.78,
    "weight": 79.34
}
```

And the Dotfuscater obfuscates it to this:

```
Console.WriteLine((object) JObject.FromObject((object) new global::b<string, int, double, double>("John Doe", 34, 1.78, 79.34)));
```

And then the output is this:

```
{}
```

How can I use anonymous classes with the Dotfuscator without this problem?

EDIT:

Full code:

```
public static class Example
{
    static void LogPerson()
    {
        JObject personJson = JObject.FromObject(
            new
            {
                name = "John Doe",
                age = 34,
                height = 1.78,
                weight = 79.34
            });
        Console.WriteLine(JSONObject);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You/I could use a dynamic object, like this:

```
dynamic person = new ExpandoObject();
person.name = "John Doe";
person.age = 34;
person.height = 1.78;
person.weight = 79.34;

JObject personJson = JObject.FromObject(person);

Console.WriteLine(personJson);
```

It looks very weird when it's obfuscated but it does work. The output is exactly as expected.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like Dotfuscator is removing the properties even though you don't want it to. (It does that because usually it's harmless, and it makes reverse-engineering harder.) You should be able to exclude those properties from renaming, which will prevent them from being removed, by configuring an exclude rule that matches the `CompilerGeneratedAttribute`. That will prevent all such properties on anonymous classes from being removed.

Here's an example of a project file (segment) that would do this:

```
<excludelist>
  <type name=".*" regex="true" excludetype="false">
    <customattribute name=".*CompilerGeneratedAttribute" regex="true" />
    <propertymember name=".*" regex="true" />
  </type>
</excludelist>
```

You can read about how to do this via the GUI in the [Community Edition docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd551425.aspx) or [Pro docs](https://www.preemptive.com/images/stories/Dotfuscator/webframe.html#The_Rename_Exclude_Tab.html).

Full disclosure: I work for PreEmptive Solutions.

Comment: Thanks you! but can you please give me a little more specific example for my situation? I don't have much experience with Dotfuscator.

Comment: Take a look at the [Community Edition docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd551425.aspx) to find the right screen. On that screen, hit 'Add Type' to add a type rule, then give it a name of `.*`. Right-click on the type in the tree, and click "Add Custom Attribute". Give it a name of `.*CompilerGeneratedAttribute`. Right-click on the type again and click "Add Property" and give it a name of `.*`. Save and build.

Answer (score 1):

I see that no one has replied to your post, so I thought I would respond with some thoughts. You probably already know these things, so I apologize ahead of time.

First, I see that from the obfuscated code, that the returned object from `JObject.FromObject` is being cast to an `object` type. Remember that if you pass any object reference to the `Console.WriteLine` method, the object's default `ToString` method will be called. Consequently, `Object.ToString()` method is being called in your example. From the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring(v=vs.110).aspx%22MSDN%22) documentation for `Object.ToString()` it states:

> Default implementations of the Object.ToString method return the fully qualified name of the object's type.

I would say that your use of an anonymous type is confusing things in a way I do not know of; but could you write a custom `ToString` extension method for the `JObject` type? Maybe something akin to:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static string ToJSONString(this JObject jo)
    {
        // You could step into this method in the VS debugger to
        // see what 'jo' looks like. You may have to use reflection
        // to get at the properties, but I've never tried it on an 
        // anonymous type. 
    }
}
```

You would then call `Console.WriteLine(JSONObject.ToJSONString());` BTW, the use of `JSONObject` as the name of a variable confuses me because it looks like a `Type`; could you use `jsonObject` instead?

I hope someone else can clarify things a bit more. Good Luck!

Comment: `JObject` is not an anonymous type, and `ToString` is a virtual method. The problem is that dotFuscator turns the anonymous object (from which the `JObject` is constructed) to a common helper generic class, thus getting rid of all the property names; reflection can't help you - that's what `JObject.FromObject` is using in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I had a hunch that my post might generate some responses. I did say I was treading in uncharted waters. Are you saying that an extension method won't work, and do you have any further suggestions for UUioP?

Comment: I'm afraid there's no way out of this other than configuration of dotFuscator - and I have no idea what kind of options that gives you, sadly :)

Comment: @RETierney, Thanks for answering my question, but the problem is not with the `JObject.FromObject()` because `Console.WriteLine(
                new
                {
                    name = "John Doe",
                    age = 34,
                    height = 1.78,
                    weight = 79.34
                });` compiles to `Console.WriteLine((object) new global::b<string, int, double, double>("John Doe", 34, 1.78, 79.34));`